# Many-to-Many with association object and all relationships defined crashes on delete

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

When having a fully fledged many-to-many with all relations described, the deletion of one of the two main objects crashes.

### Description

**Car** (`.car_ownerships`)  <-> (`.car`) **CarOwnership** (`.person`) <-> (`.car_ownerships`) **Person**

**Car** (`.people`) <-----------------> (`.cars`) **Person**

### Problem

When deleting a **Car** or a **Person**
SA first deletes the association object **CarOwnership** (because of the 'through' relationship with the `secondary` argument) and then tries to update the foreign keys to NULL in the same association objects, hence crashing.

How should I solve this? I'm a little perplexed to see that this is not addressed in the docs nor anywhere I could find online, since I thought that this pattern was quite common :-/. What am I missing?

I know I could have the `passive_deletes` switch on for the through relationship, but I'd like to keep the delete statement, just to prevent the update from happening or (make it happen before).

**Edit**: Actually, `passive_deletes` doesn't solve the problem if the dependent objects are loaded in session, as `DELETE` statement will still be issued. A solution is to use `viewonly=True`, but then I lose not only deletion but automatic creation of association objects. Also I find `viewonly=True` to be quite dangerous, because it lets you `append()` without persisting!

### REPEX

#### Setup

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo = False)
Base = declarative_base()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()


class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))

    cars = relationship('Car', secondary='car_ownerships', backref='people')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Person {} [{}]>'.format(self.name, self.id)

class Car(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cars'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Car {} [{}]>'.format(self.name, self.id)


class CarOwnership(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'car_ownerships'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String(255))
    car_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey(Car.id))
    car = relationship('Car', backref='car_ownerships')
    person_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey(Person.id))
    person = relationship('Person', backref='car_ownerships')

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Ownership [{}]: {} <<-{}->> {}'.format(self.id, self.car, self.type, self.person)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

#### Filing objects

```py
antoine = Person(name='Antoine')
rob = Person(name='Rob')
car1 = Car(name="Honda Civic")
car2 = Car(name='Renault Espace')

CarOwnership(person=antoine, car=car1, type = "secondary")
CarOwnership(person=antoine, car=car2, type = "primary")
CarOwnership(person=rob, car=car1, type = "primary")

session.add(antoine)
session.commit()

session.query(CarOwnership).all()
```

#### Deleting -> Crashing

```py
print('#### DELETING')
session.delete(car1)
print('#### COMMITING')
session.commit()


# StaleDataError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
# <ipython-input-6-80498b2f20a3> in <module>()
#       1 session.delete(car1)
# ----> 2 session.commit()
# ...
```

#### Diagnostics

The explanation I propose above is backed by the SQL statements given by the engine with `echo=True`:

```py
#### DELETING
#### COMMITING
2016-07-07 16:55:28,893 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT persons.id AS persons_id, persons.name AS persons_name 
FROM persons, car_ownerships 
WHERE ? = car_ownerships.car_id AND persons.id = car_ownerships.person_id
2016-07-07 16:55:28,894 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (1,)
2016-07-07 16:55:28,895 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT car_ownerships.id AS car_ownerships_id, car_ownerships.type AS car_ownerships_type, car_ownerships.car_id AS car_ownerships_car_id, car_ownerships.person_id AS car_ownerships_person_id 
FROM car_ownerships 
WHERE ? = car_ownerships.car_id
2016-07-07 16:55:28,896 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (1,)
2016-07-07 16:55:28,898 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine DELETE FROM car_ownerships WHERE car_ownerships.car_id = ? AND car_ownerships.person_id = ?
2016-07-07 16:55:28,898 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ((1, 1), (1, 2))
2016-07-07 16:55:28,900 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine UPDATE car_ownerships SET car_id=? WHERE car_ownerships.id = ?
2016-07-07 16:55:28,900 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ((None, 1), (None, 2))
2016-07-07 16:55:28,901 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
```

## EDITS

### Using `association_proxy`

We can use association proxies to try and materialize the 'through' relationship.

Nevertheless, in order to `.append()` a dependent object directly, we need to create a constructor for the association object. This constructor must be 'hacked' to be made bi-directional, so we can use both assignments:

```py
my_car.people.append(Person(name='my_son'))
my_husband.cars.append(Car(name='new_shiny_car'))
```

The resulting (midly tested) code is below, but I don't feel quite comfortable with it (what else is going to break because of this hacky constructor?).

**EDIT:** The way to go with association proxies is presented in RazerM's answer below. `association_proxy()` has a creator argument that alleviates the need for the monstrous constructor I ended up using below.

```py
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))

    cars = association_proxy('car_ownerships', 'car')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Person {} [{}]>'.format(self.name, self.id)

class Car(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cars'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))

    people = association_proxy('car_ownerships', 'person')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Car {} [{}]>'.format(self.name, self.id)


class CarOwnership(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'car_ownerships'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String(255))
    car_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey(Car.id))
    car = relationship('Car', backref='car_ownerships')
    person_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey(Person.id))
    person = relationship('Person', backref='car_ownerships')

    def __init__(self, car=None, person=None, type='secondary'):
        if isinstance(car, Person):
            car, person = person, car
        self.car = car
        self.person = person
        self.type = type        

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Ownership [{}]: {} <<-{}->> {}'.format(self.id, self.car, self.type, self.person)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cleanest solution is below and doesn't involve association proxies. It is the missing recipe for fully-fledged many-through-many relations.

Here, we edit the direct relations that go from the dependent objects **Car** and **Person** to the association object **CarOwnership**, in order to prevent these relationships to issue an `UPDATE` after the association object has been deleted. To this end, we use the `passive_deletes='all'` flag.

The resulting interaction is:

- ability to query and set the association object from the dependent objects

```py
    # Changing Ownership type:
    my_car.car_ownerships[0].type = 'primary'
    # Creating an ownership between a car and a person directly:
    CarOwnership(car=my_car, person=my_husband, type='primary')
```

- ability to access and edit dependent objects directly:

  ```py
  # Get all cars from a person:
  [print(c) for c in my_husband.cars]
  # Update the name of one of my cars:
  me.cars[0].name = me.cars[0].name + ' Cabriolet'
  ```
- automatic creation and deletion of the association object when creation or deletion of a dependent objects

  ```py
  # Create a new owner and assign it to a car:
  my_car.people.append(Person('my_husband'))
  session.add(my_car)
  session.commit() # Creates the necessary CarOwnership
  # Delete a car:
  session.delete(my_car)
  session.commit() # Deletes all the related CarOwnership objects
  ```

### Code

```py
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))

    cars = relationship('Car', secondary='car_ownerships', backref='people')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Person {} [{}]>'.format(self.name, self.id)

class Car(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cars'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Car {} [{}]>'.format(self.name, self.id)


class CarOwnership(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'car_ownerships'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String(255))
    car_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey(Car.id))
    car = relationship('Car', backref=backref('car_ownerships', passive_deletes='all'))
    person_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey(Person.id))
    person = relationship('Person', backref=backref('car_ownerships', passive_deletes='all'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Ownership [{}]: {} <<-{}->> {}'.format(self.id, self.car, self.type, self.person)
```

Answer (score 5):

You're using an [Association Object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object), so you need to do things differently.

I've changed the relationships here, look at them carefully because it's a little hard to wrap your head around at first (at least it was for me!).

I've used `back_populates` because it's clearer than `backref` in this case. Both sides of the many-to-many relationship must refer to `CarOwnership` directly, since it's that object you'll be working with. This is also what your example shows; you need to use it so that you can set `type`.

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))

    cars = relationship('CarOwnership', back_populates='person')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Person {} [{}]>'.format(self.name, self.id)


class Car(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cars'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))

    people = relationship('CarOwnership', back_populates='car')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Car {} [{}]>'.format(self.name, self.id)


class CarOwnership(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'car_ownerships'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String(255))
    car_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey(Car.id))
    person_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey(Person.id))

    car = relationship('Car', back_populates='people')
    person = relationship('Person', back_populates='cars')

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Ownership [{}]: {} <<-{}->> {}'.format(self.id, self.car, self.type, self.person)
```

Note that after deleting either side, the `car_ownerships` row will not be deleted, it will just set the foreign keys to NULL. I can add more to my answer if you'd like to set up automatic deletion.

**Edit:** to directly access collections of `Car` and `Person` objects, you need to use `association_proxy`, the classes then change to this:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))

    cars = association_proxy(
        'cars_association', 'car', creator=lambda c: CarOwnership(car=c))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Person {} [{}]>'.format(self.name, self.id)


class Car(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cars'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))

    people = association_proxy(
        'people_association', 'person', creator=lambda p: CarOwnership(person=p))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Car {} [{}]>'.format(self.name, self.id)


class CarOwnership(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'car_ownerships'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String(255), default='secondary')
    car_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey(Car.id))
    person_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey(Person.id))

    car = relationship('Car', backref='people_association')
    person = relationship('Person', backref='cars_association')

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Ownership [{}]: {} <<-{}->> {}'.format(self.id, self.car, self.type, self.person)
```

**Edit:** In your edit, you made a mistake when you converted it to use `backref`. Your association proxies for car and person can't both use the 'car_ownerships' relationship, which is why I had one called 'people_association', and one called 'cars_association'.

The 'car_ownerships'  relationship you have is unrelated to the fact that the association table is called 'car_ownerships', hence why I named them differently.

I have modified the code block above. To allow append to work, you need to add a creator to the association proxy. I have changed `back_populates` to `backref`, and added the default `type` to the `Column` object rather than the constructor.

Comment: But this is not what I want to do. Here you just renamed the `car_ownerships` relations (that were defined in `backref`) into `cars` and `people`, and you removed the through relation. The `cars` and `people` in your proposal are not really **Car** and **Person** objects, just **CarOwnership**. 
Is there no way to get a through relation with association objects in SA? Do I have to use association proxies for this?

Comment: Correct. I added an example of using `association_proxy`.

Comment: Thank you! But your example doesn't work (have you tested it?) because it lacks a constructor it seems. See my edit.

Comment: I modified the second code block to do this without creating a custom constructor on `CarOwnership`.

Comment: It still doesn't work - I get a type error when trying to do: `my_car.people.append(Person(name='my_child'))`. Also I can't really see what edits you made?

Comment: It does work. Replace the 3 classes from your question with the second code block I posted. You can click "edited x mins ago" below my answer to see a diff.

Comment: I didn't know about the diff trick - neat! And I actually copy-pasted your code to run it in a notebook, with no luck. Also nothing prevents me from having the backrefs being the same since they are applied to different objects, **Car** and **Person**.

Comment: You didn't post a traceback or even an error message. https://gist.github.com/RazerM/1cb878ae645e4c973c71dbd22bf692be

Comment: I did tell you the error type, and I couldn't post the full traceback in a comment. And the solution you posted *did not work* until your final change so answering 'it does work' doesn't really help much either. **Thank you** for the final solution you provided. Using a creator is the way to go with association proxies, much cleaner than my constructor-based method (adapted from the doc). I ended up using a different method altogether that seemed more direct (see my answer below), which seems to be equivalent in the end?

Comment: What final changes? The latest edit is _before_ your comment about getting the type error. I also posted the gist which is the code from your question combined with the most recent edit.

Comment: You're right, my bad. I must've used an outdated version of your code. I still don't understand when you say "Your association proxies for car and person can't both use the 'car_ownerships' relationship". I don't think this is true, as nothing prevents me from using the same name for two different relationships, starting from Car and Person.