# How do you do many to many with more than 2 tables?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-appbuilder

I have a table for Logs that contains various information about employees
ex:

```
class Log(Model):
    division_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('division.id'), nullable=False)
    division = relationship("Division")

    employee_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("employee.id"), nullable=False)
    employee = relationship("Employee") 

    skill_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("skill.id"), nullable=False)
    skill = relationship("Skill")

    message = Column(String, default='OK', nullable=False)
    date = Column(DateTime, default=NowTime(), nullable=True)
```

Employee and Skill Tables look like this:

```
class Employee(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    division_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('division.id'), nullable=False)
    division = relationship("Division")

class Skill(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
```

I am currently using Flask-Appbuilder and I have a Skill View that displays all the logs for the current selected skill.

```
class LogView(ModelView):
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(Log)
    list_columns = ['division', 'employee', 'skill', 'message', 'date']
    show_template = 'appbuilder/general/model/show_cascade.html'

class SkillLogView(ModelView):
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(Skill)
    list_columns = ['name']
    related_views = [LogView]
    show_template = 'appbuilder/general/model/show_cascade.html'
```

In the SkillLogView, I also want to display a list of employee names that have this skill.

How do I also get the employees from the logs that pertain to the current skill ?

I am not sure how to do it, but I thought it might be a case for many to many. The problem is that there are 3 tables, not 2.

Is there a way to do many to many with more than 2 tables ?

Or is there another way to accomplish what I want to do ?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Employee` has not established any relationship with `Log`, so querying `Employee` using join with `Log` for a predicate is difficult.

However, you can simply query the `Log` for `employee_id` with the `skill_id` as a subquery, and fetch `Employee` with the given result.

```python
# Subquery returns `employee_id` from `logs` with the given `skill_id`
sq = session.query(Log.employee_id).\
    filter(Log.skill_id == skill_id).\
    subquery()

# Fetch `Employee` that matches `employee_id` in `sq`
q = session.query(Employee).\
    filter(Employee.employee_id.in_(sq))

employees = q.all()  # or paginate, e.g. q.limit(..).all()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Ivan !

Also, I have posted another method that implements it at the Table Model level. 

Check it out when you have time.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I've mentioned your `Your Employee has not established any relationship with Log...`, this is exactly what your other method advocates.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example online that does this very thing!

It has a person table, car table, car ownership table.

All I had to do was substitute employee for person, skill for car, and log for car ownership.

Reference URL: 
[Many-to-Many with association object and all relationships defined crashes on delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38248415/many-to-many-with-association-object-and-all-relationships-defined-crashes-on-de)

Updated Code:

```
class Log(Model):
    division_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('division.id'), nullable=False)
    division = relationship("Division")

    employee_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("employee.id"), nullable=False)
    employee = relationship("Employee", backref=backref('log', passive_deletes='all'))

    skill_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("skill.id"), nullable=False)
    skill = relationship("Skill", backref=backref('log', passive_deletes='all'))

    message = Column(String, default='OK', nullable=False)
    date = Column(DateTime, default=NowTime(), nullable=True)


class Skill(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)

    employees = relationship('Employee', secondary='log', backref='skill')


class Employee(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)

    division_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('division.id'), nullable=False)
    division = relationship("Division")

    skills = relationship('Skill', secondary='log', backref='employee')
```